# Cannot instantiate EnumMap with dynamic class argument for enums with methods

Tags: java, class, enums, runtime, enum-map

I stumbled across a strange difference in behaviour between enums in Java without any defined methods and those that do: In the latter case, `Enum.class` and `Enum.getClass()` actually refer to different compiled classes, i.e. `!Enum.class.equals(Enum.getClass())`; This causes problems when trying to e.g. instantiate an `EnumMap` with a class specified only at runtime:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

public class EnumMapTest {

    private enum TestEnum {
        FOO;
    }

    private enum TestEnumWithMethod {
        BAR {
            @Override
            protected void doSomething() {
            }
        };

        protected abstract void doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Testing enum %s...", TestEnum.class));

        final Class<TestEnum> enumStaticClass = TestEnum.class;
        System.out.println(String.format("EnumMap construction using static %s...", enumStaticClass));
        new EnumMap<TestEnum, Object>(enumStaticClass);

        final Class<TestEnum> enumDynamicClass = (Class<TestEnum>) TestEnum.FOO.getClass();
        System.out.println("Are the static and dynamic classes equal? " + enumStaticClass.equals(enumDynamicClass));
        System.out.println(String.format("EnumMap construction using dynamic %s...", enumDynamicClass));
        new EnumMap<TestEnum, Object>(enumDynamicClass);


        System.out.println(String.format("Testing enum %s...", TestEnumWithMethod.class));

        final Class<TestEnumWithMethod> enumWithMethodStaticClass = TestEnumWithMethod.class;
        System.out.println(String.format("EnumMap construction using static %s...", enumWithMethodStaticClass));
        new EnumMap<TestEnumWithMethod, Object>(enumWithMethodStaticClass);

        final Class<TestEnumWithMethod> enumWithMethodDynamicClass = (Class<TestEnumWithMethod>) TestEnumWithMethod.BAR.getClass();
        System.out.println("Are the static and dynamic classes equal? " + enumWithMethodStaticClass.equals(enumWithMethodDynamicClass));
        System.out.println(String.format("EnumMap construction using dynamic %s...", enumWithMethodDynamicClass));
        new EnumMap<TestEnumWithMethod, Object>(enumWithMethodDynamicClass);
    }
}
```

The corresponding console output is:

```
Testing enum class EnumMapTest$TestEnum...
EnumMap construction using static class EnumMapTest$TestEnum...
Are the static and dynamic classes equal? true
EnumMap construction using dynamic class EnumMapTest$TestEnum...
Testing enum class EnumMapTest$TestEnumWithMethod...
EnumMap construction using static class EnumMapTest$TestEnumWithMethod...
Are the static and dynamic classes equal? false
EnumMap construction using dynamic class EnumMapTest$TestEnumWithMethod$1...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.EnumMap.initialization(EnumMap.java:726)
    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:395)
    at EnumMapTest.main(EnumMapTest.java:46)
```

Why are there two classes made for the enum with methods? Why does this cause problems during the instantiation of `EnumMap`? How can I get around this to create an instance without knowing the exact enum type at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: `Enum.getClass()` gets the anonymous class of the particular enum instance, e.g. `FOO` or `BAR`, while `Enum.getDeclaringClass()` gets the class of the actual enum. Strange that the latter stills works without methods, though...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the multiple classes is that the different `enum` methods are implemented by creating an anonymous inner class (the `$1`) for each `enum` value, just as if you'd declared some inline `ActionListener`. The "workaround" is to use the actual `enum` class (`TestEnumWithMethod`), not the class of a value of that enum; if you know enough information to safely use an `EnumMap`, you know enough information to use the `enum`'s "native" type.

Comment: That wasn't my question: In my case I don't have the class info at compile time. See my answer below

Comment: @errantlinguist Please elaborate on your perceived use case. Any generic method that is going to be creating an `EnumMap` or otherwise needing to know the `enum` class is going to have to have the class as an input (such as for `EnumSet#noneOf`); if you pass in a `BAR`, you'll still have to be listing `TestEnumWithMethod` as the type parameter for whatever you're passing it to.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you answered the "why" part of my question, but if I post the actual implementation issue I have, people will tell me to post a "minimal working example".

In my case, I have a container of `Enum` instances which is not an `EnumSet`-- my exact case, a `List`, because I need to order the enums. I generalised the method to work with multiple enum types, and it worked in all cases except where the enums have methods defined.

Comment: @errantlinguist Well, sometimes "minimal" is still pretty big. ;-)

Comment: Also, it can sometimes be a bit difficult explaining to your boss why you spent e.g. 2 hours trying to create a "big enough" minimal working example out of multiple classes and 1000s of lines of code just so you can post it on SO ;)